# Mod_Rewrite Complicated!

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, subdirectory

I'd like to set up a redirect/rewrite in my .htaccess that does the following:

A few samples of redirects I'm trying to accomplish:

domain.com/08/04/10/file.php to domain.com/new/file.php
domain.com/06/01/11/file2.php to domain.com/new/file2.php
domain.com/07/12/07/file3.php to domain.com/new/file3.php

You get the idea. I don't even know where to start - there are so many sub-directories and sub-sub-directories that my head is spinning. I want them all to go to /new/filename.php. There are 3 subdirectories I'm trying to redirect; /06/, /07/, and /08/. Each has 2 levels below it, and a few php files in the 3rd level. Any suggestions on how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$    new/$4?d=$1,$2,$3 [L,R]
```

This should turn the first into the second.

1. /01/02/03/myfile.php
2. /new/myfile.php?d=01,02,03

I've assumed that you need the folder names as parameters in the PHP call, and that the folders will all be numeric, 2 characters, as it looks strangely like a 2-char-per-part data format ... but if that's not the case, let me know.